# HTML Button Won't Change JS Variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, canvas, onclick

Using JS, on a canvas, I have a ball moving across the canvas. It works fine.

I have created a button element in HTML and I want the function, "changeBallDirection()" to be called onclick.

changeBallDirection() should change the variable xBallDirection, which should change the direction of the ball.

The variable xBallDirection doesn't change. I printed xBallDirection on the canvas to confirm it wasn't changing. Code is below. First time posting, so please let me know any basic breaches in etiquette I may have committed. Thanks.

```
                <script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
                void setup() {
                    size(400, 400);
                };
                frameRate(20);
                var r=0;
                var xBallDirection = 1;
                var changeBallDirection = function (direction) {
                    xBallDirection = direction;
                };
                //draw ball on canvas and move to the right
                void draw() {
                    fill(45, 56, 99);
                    ellipse(100+r, 34, 34, 34);
                    r=r+xBallDirection;
                    //I printed xBallDirection here so that I could see if it changed when the button was pushed
                    text(xBallDirection,50,50);
                };

            </script>

            <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:blue" onclick="changeBallDirection(-10)">Ball Left</button>

            <canvas id="pjs"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Syberspace, I moved the changeBallDirection above draw() so that it is global. I upated the code above to reflect the changes I made but xBallDirection is still not changed onclick.

Comment: @Syberpace, do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`changeBallDirection` is not in the global namespace and therefore cannot be called within the onclick event.
You should get something like `ReferenceError: changeBallDirection is not defined` in your console when you click the button.

Move the function outside of the draw() portion of your script and everything should work fine.